# JavaScript сценарий когда пользователь не воодит даных

Tags: javascript, html

есть сайт с регистрационной формой, поля ввода сделаны с помощью тегов 
и есть отдельное диалоговое окно, в котором нужно вывести текст, если спустя некоторое время(допустим 30 секунд) пользователь не введет данных в поля,вот то что я смог написать

```
 if(){
function ptr(){
document.getElementById("ptr").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("dia").style.background = "red";
}
let timerId = setInterval(() => ptr(), 30000);
```

}

document.getElementById("ptr").style.display = "block"; - делает блок с текстом видимым.
Нужно сделать так, что эта функция срабатывала только если пользователь не введёт данных.

Answer (score -1):

Проверьте поле на пустоту.

```html
element1 = document.getElementById(id);

if(element1 != null)
{
    //code to set the value variable.
}
```

Comment: Вы здесь не проверяете поле на пустоту. Вы проверяете на наличие тега с определенным id.

Comment: Вам может решить задачу за Вас? Чтобы вы смогли скопировать и вставить себе ее, если сами ленитесь разобраться в детском уровне.

Comment: Во первых - я не автор вопроса. Во вторых - зачем ответ, который не отвечает на вопрос? В третьих - уровень у всех разный.

Answer (score -1):

Можно проверить innerHTML элемента на пустоту

```js
const ptr =() => {
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  //var ptr = document.getElementById("ptr");
  var dia = document.getElementById("dia");
  if (!input.value){
    //ptr.style.display = "block";
    dia.style.background = "red";
  }
}
let timerId = setInterval(ptr, 30000);
```

```css
#dia{
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  background:black;
}
#input{
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dia">
<input type="text" id="input"/>
</div>
```

Comment: У тега `<input>` нету `innerHtml`. Точнее, он всегда будет пустой.